# Using Node.js Cluster Module on Openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to use both cpus on openshift gears with node.js, but i have no idea on how to proceed with cluster module as the port is a openshift variable. Do i assign arbitrary values for the ports or use the same variable for the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift will only give you access to one core per application instance (per "gear").

If you want to cluster Nodejs on OpenShift, I'd recommend using OpenShift's HAProxy tooling to scale up and down.

I wrote up a few notes on this topic here: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/10-reasons-openshift-is-the-best-place-to-host-your-nodejs-app#scale

Comment: cpus().length returns 2, so i guess i can spawn two processes

Comment: You can spawn additional processes, but OpenShift's loadbalancer won't hand out additional port+IP pairs for that process to bind to.  The lb won't be directing any traffic to this additional process.